# How can I use PHP's gettext in conjunction with python's gettext?

Tags: php, python, gettext

I have an app that I'm migrating portions of to Django, but Python and PHP have a different string format,  e.g., `"Hello %1s"` in PHP vs. `"Hello {0}"` or `"Hello {name}"` in Python.

We'll be maintaining both apps for a while, but is there a way to use the Python format in PHP or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

PHP's gettext doesn't expand/substitute %s - this is done by output functions (e.g. *printf*).
It also appears to be the case in Python.

Most importantly, in Python you **can** use %s to represent strings, see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

So you should be able to use %s-style strings in both.

Comment: That's part of sprintf to order the arguments:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: you are correct - I've never used order specifiers, so wrongly assumed these do not exist :)

Comment: Have you had a look at %s in Python?

Comment: Yep, and I've used '%s' before, but then we'd lose ordering - which for us would be important - but it may work for some strings.

Comment: Can you specify string values in the order they are used in the format string, so as to avoid using ordering modifiers at all? I do not know if Django imposes any limits on that.

An alternative solution could be to use $-style variables in-string in PHP - i.e. _("Hello $1!") - and to regex-replace all $([\d]+) occurrences to {\1} for Python. This would be inefficient and extra verbose, but other than that I can't see any other solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this php PECL extension help you?

http://pecl.php.net/package/python

Regards.